# How to customize message in a Facebook app request

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've noticed that some applications on facebook are able to send out invite requests with customized text. According to the facebook documentation, an app can customize the message text of a facebook app request (the custom message is not displayed on an invite request however), but there is no explanation of how to customize the notification text.

How do you customize the text of the notification itself?

Documentation at: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/

Answer (score 0):

The customized text is set via the **message** parameter.

Answer (score 0):

There was a undocumented boolean parameter named "new_style_message" that used to work. Don't know about now. Example:

```
   {
      // here, your parameters...
      new_style_message : true
   }
```